# the key you provided doesn't work with this thing error in Thing space GET opertion

Tags: json, api

While i am performing a GET operation in Thing space, it was showing the following error.
**Request URL**

```
https://thingspace.io:443/dweet/for/pathetic-honey?  key=fZC4GAPSVxMrBVrG9HvQgGfg7Rsa
```

**Response Body**

```
{  
  "this": "failed",  
  "because": "the key you provided doesn't work with this thing"  
}
```

**Response Code**

200

**Response Headers**

```
{  
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  
  "Date": "Thu, 23 Mar 2017 09:09:45 GMT",  
  "Content-Encoding": "gzip",  
  "Connection": "keep-alive",  
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",  
  "Content-Type": "application/json"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the question. don't pass the **key_value** while you are passing the API. 
just pass the thing name only.
eg:**https://thingspace.io/dweet/for/YOUR_THINGNAME**